# Can I change Storage Type from HDD to SSD on Cloud SQL after creating an instance? (GCP)

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I'm trying to change **Storage Type** from **HDD** to **SSD** on **Cloud SQL** after creating an instance as shown below but there are no options to do it:

[image]

Is it impossible to change **Storage Type** from **HDD** to **SSD** on **Cloud SQL** after creating an instance? If impossible, are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's impossible to change **Storage Type** from **HDD** to **SSD** on **Cloud SQL** after creating an instance because **Storage Type** is **immutable** after creating an instance.

But, if you really want to change **Storage Type** from **HDD** to **SSD** on **Cloud SQL**, you can **export data from your old instance created with HDD** :

[image]

Then, **import the data into your newly created instance with SSD**. This way, you can change **Storage Type** from **HDD** to **SSD** on **Cloud SQL** after creating an instance:

[image]

This is what [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/choosing-ssd-hdd#switching) actually suggests:

### Switch between SSD and HDD storage

When you create a Cloud SQL instance, your choice of SSD or HDD storage for the instance is permanent.

If you need to convert an existing HDD instance to SSD, or conversely, you can export the data from the existing instance and import the data into a new instance. Keep in mind that migrating an entire instance takes time.

Comment: How to that without downtime when the SSD size is 5.24 TB?